# Pass text to panel with toggle

Tags: javascript, html

When I click the link of the panel, I would like to have text passed to the panel body. I have placed the onClick in each of the panel tags including the  tag. The onClick calls myFunction, which is supposed to send text to the body of the panel. That is not happening. Any suggestions?

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementId("panel-body").innerHTML = "it worked"
};
```

```html
<div class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" onClick="myFunction">Name</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the function with `()`: `onClick="myFunction()"`

The selector you tried to use would be `.getElementById()`, but in this case you want a more specific element. So the the css-selector would be `#collapse1 > .panel-body` which selects the elements with class `panel-body` which are direct children of `#collapse1`.

`querySelector()` selects the first element which fulfills the given css selector, `querySelectorAll()` would return all of them in an array-like structor [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelector("#collapse1 > .panel-body").innerHTML = "it worked"
};
```

```html
<div class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" onClick="myFunction()">Name</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` does not return an `Array`. It returns a node list/HTML collection.

Comment: Yes but for the most sake it's an array, I edited it

Comment: No, it's not. Many of the `Array` methods will throw errors if you try to call them on a node list.